# Alternative of Chuck - HTTP inspector for Android

Tags: android

I was using [Chuck](https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck) for inspection of HTTP(S) requests/responses fired by my Android App. It was working fine before but as I am working on new project now I came to realize that for targetSdkVersion 31 and above its causing [issue](https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck/issues/103).

Is there any good alternative library for inspection of HTTP requests? any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: are you looking only for in app solution?

Comment: @AnatoliiChub preferably in app but if there is any other solution then please feel free to share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Chucker](https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker) instead of Chuck, which is well maintained.

Answer (score 1):

If you considering not only in app solutions you can use:
Fiddler or Charles for sniffing traffic from your device.

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/
https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Another useful tool that you can use - Stetho, detailed instruction how to launch it you can find here:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-network-traffic-with-stetho-and-chrome-developer-tools

Also you can use Android studio network profiler/inspector(depends on version of Android studio you use it has different name)
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler